# Any possibility to load a TIF Image in a VB Form

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Any possibility to load a TIF Image in a VB Form, if so kindly share code

Comment: Why `Tif` why not any other format? :) Just curious.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to use a webcontrol.
In the userform-designer, right-click on the toolbox, and select additional controls... then `Microsoft Web Browser`.
Code might be something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate2 _
    "about:<body style=""background:url('F:\Test.tif')"">&nbsp;</body>"
End Sub
```

It worked, but is quite complicated and might be slow.